# Error viewing Orders - Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, orders, order-grid

When attempting to view an order in Magento 2.2.5 I receive the following error...

```
Order View

Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.
```

This is our first order so can't say how long this problem has been present.  I have tried a test order which also has the same problem.

This is a default install with only m2epro installed, no other modules that don't come as standard and running the default Luma theme.

Has anybody come across this issue? I have googled to no avail

edit: still no solution found

Comment: Can you disable the extension m2epro and test again?

Comment: Can you disable the m2epro extension and check log files?

Comment: M2e disabled, still unable to view orders.  There are no errors in system.log, is there another log file?